# SharePoint 2016 Search Topology with Minrole

Tags: search, 2016, topology

How does the Search Service application Topology work in SharePoint 2016?
I'm planning on having 2 search server, does that mean when I create the service application, I will be running all the search components (Crawl, Query, Index) on those Search Minrole servers only?

Answer (score 2):

True! When you created a farm using minrole, your search severs will run the following (search) services:

- Search Administration Web Service
- Search Host Controller Service
- Search Query and Site Settings Service
- SharePoint Server Search

No other server will run any other search service, meaning that the entire search topology will run on those two search servers.

See: [Description of MinRole and associated services in SharePoint Server 2016](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt667910(v=office.16).aspx)